# Prevent implicit instanciation in class template

Tags: c++, templates, implicit

I'm trying to declare class B such as written below. The problem is, as far as I know, `A<B, T1>` is actually implicitly considered as `A<B<T1>, T1>` which doesn't match class A definition. Therefore, my question is: is it possible to use class B inside its own definition, in its "template-non-instanciated" form? And if so how?

```
template <template <class T1> class T2, class T1>
class A {

};

template <class T1>
class B {
A<B, T1>* example;
};
```

which results in the following compilation error with gcc4.2 :

error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template < template < class T1 > class T2, class T1 > class A'

error:   expected a class template, got 'B< T1 >'

Comment: maybe the policy clone idiom is something for you

Comment: Can you either give us a complete example that fails to compile or at least tell us which compiler fails to compile this? When I add a `main` that instantiates `B<int>` it compiles fine with g++ 4.4 and 4.5.

Comment: "The problem is, as far as I know..."  ― no error message, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in g++-4.2 as I can reproduce your problem with that compiler.

If you can move to at least 4.4 your code will compile as-is. Alternately you can write `A< ::B, T1>* example;` to force it to use the global scope template, which compiles in 4.2.